# Quiero mostrar datos en una tabla incremental utilizando un for en PHP

Tags: php

Quiero que los datos aparezcan del 1 al 10, del 10 al uno, par e impar, ya tengo los resultados solo me falta crear el código para que los resultados me lo devuelva en la tabla.
Estoy batallando por que no se como imprimir la tabla al final y solo mandar a llamar los resultados pero hasta el final, intente que cada variable en cada for se llame diferente y llamarlos al final en la tabla pero no me funciono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <?php

      //Numeros del 1 al 10
       for ( $i = 1; $i<=10; $i++ ){
         echo "<br>".$i;
       }
         echo "<br>";

      //Numeros del 10 al 1
      for ( $i = 10; $i>=1; $i--){
       echo "<br>".$i;
      }

      echo "<br>";


      //Numeros de 2 en 2 hasta el 20 
     for ( $i = 2; $i<=20; $i++){
       if($i%2==0){
        echo "<br>".$i;
        }
     }
     echo "<br>";


    //Numeros primos
    for ( $i = 0; $i<=20; $i++){
         if($i % 2){
         echo "<br>".$i;
     }

     }
       //numeros de 5 en 5 hasta el 45
        echo "<br>"; 
        for ( $i = 0; $i<=45; $i++){
         if($i%5==0){
          echo "<br>".$i;
        }

       }
        echo "<br>"; 


       //Con este codigo ya me devuelve la tabla pero solo del 1 al 10
        echo "<br>";
         for ( $i = 1; $i<=10; $i++)

       {
         echo 
          "<table>
                <th>$i</th>
                <th>$i</th>
                <th>$i</th>
                <th>$i</th>
           </table>"; 
    }


       ?>
```

Comment: y quieres que todos salgan en una tabla diferente, verdad?

Comment: No que sea en la misma tabla

Comment: Así como la imagen que acabo de poner. Así debería salir todos los resultados juntos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple sería ir concatenando.

Aquí, para que el código no quede tan confuso, concatenamos todo en una variable  `$mTable`.

Si quieres organizarlo de otro modo, lo puedes hacer libremente.

Para ayuda a visualizar he metido la tabla dentro de un `div` y le he puesto clases propias de la librería `Bulma`. Puedes cambiar esas clases por las de tu librería, si usas alguna.

### Edit

Para imprimir cada grupo como una columna he creado un array asociativo con cada valor de los diferentes `for` con una clave (`one, two, three`...) y luego he sacado otro array agrupando cada valor de los grupos en sus respectivas columnas.

### PHP

```
$arrData=array();

for ( $i = 1; $i<=10; $i++ ){
    $mData['one'][]=$i; 
}

for ( $i = 10; $i>=1; $i--){
    $mData['two'][]=$i; 
}

for ( $i = 2; $i<=20; $i++){
    if($i%2==0){
        $mData['three'][]=$i;
    }
 }

for ( $i = 0; $i<=20; $i++){
    if($i % 2){
        $mData['four'][]=$i;;
    }
}

for ( $i = 0; $i<=45; $i++){
    if($i%5==0){
        $mData['five'][]=$i;;
    }
}

foreach($mData as $key => $row) {
   foreach($row as $group => $value) { 
       $newData[$group][] = $value;
   }
}

$mTable="<div class=\"table-container\">";
$mTable.="<table class=\"table is-bordered is-stripped\">";
$mTable.="<tr><th>1 a 10</th><th>10 a 1</th><th>2 en 2</th><th>Primos</th><th>5 en 5</th></tr>";

foreach ($newData as $row){
    $mTable.="<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $k=>$v){
        $mTable.="<td>$v</td>";
    }
    $mTable.="</tr>";
}

echo $mTable;
```

---

### HTML

Se producirá algo así, aquí de dejo el preview

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="table-container">
  <table class="table is-bordered is-stripped">
    <tr>
      <th>1 a 10</th>
      <th>10 a 1</th>
      <th>2 en 2</th>
      <th>Primos</th>
      <th>5 en 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Ok, las respuestas salen horizontales, si deseo que salgan verticales que tendría que hacer?.

Comment: @IsabelMiranda sólo tienes que cambiar los `td` por `tr`... a ver si me da tiempo de hacer una muestra...

Comment: No me funciona :(

Comment: @IsabelMiranda revisa ahora...

Comment: Si, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma alternativa de crear esa tabla, puede ser generando un `array` de 2 dimensiones, donde cada fila seran los valores secuenciales.

Una vez generado el `array`, se intercambian las filas por las columnas, y así ya se puede imprimir las filas normalmente.

**NOTA 1**: La última columna en sus dos primeros elementos (1 y 5) no tienen una separación igual, como todos los demás elementos, por eso en mi ejemplo lo inicialicé en 0. También podrías cambiarlo de 5 a 50 en la llamada a la función.

```
<?php

$tabla[] = range(1, 10, 1);
$tabla[] = range(10, 1, 1);
$tabla[] = range(2, 20, 2);
$tabla[] = range(1, 19, 2);
$tabla[] = range(0, 45, 5);

array_unshift($tabla, NULL); // ** Nota 2
$tabla = call_user_func_array('array_map', $tabla); // ** Nota 2

echo '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">'.PHP_EOL;
foreach($tabla as $fila) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($fila as $col) {
        echo '<td>' . $col . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</table>'.PHP_EOL;
```

**NOTA 2**: [Transposing multidimensional arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797251/transposing-multidimensional-arrays-in-php) 
Adicional, como se puede leer ahí, en PHP 5.6 o superior, se puede cambiar esas dos lineas por:

```
$tabla = array_map(NULL, ...$tabla);
```

- [Argument upacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Comment: Muchas gracias, aun se me hace muy avanzado tu código.

Comment: @IsabelMiranda No hay problema, solo es una referencia para ti (en el futuro) u otras personas, aunque sea una respuesta más avanzada. La versión fácil ya la pusieron en la otra respuesta.

Comment: Si muchas gracias, ya me funciono con la anterior. :)